# JSON SCHEMA - How can i check a values exists in an array

Tags: jsonschema

I have a simple question. I have a property **groupBy** which is an array and contain only two possible values "product" and "date". Now i want to make another property required based upon a *value exists* in the **groupBy** array. In this case when my **groupBy** array contains **"date"** i want to make resolution required! How can i do that ?

Who can i check if an array contains a value ?

```
var data = {
    "pcsStreamId": 123123,
    "start": moment().valueOf(),
    "end": moment().valueOf(),
    "groupBy" : ["product"]
};

var schema = {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "pcsStreamId": { "type": "number" },
            "start": { "type": "integer", "minimum" : 0 },
            "end": { "type": "integer", "minimum" : 0 },
            "groupBy": {
                "type": "array",
                "uniqueItems": true,
                "items" : {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["product", "date"]
                },
               "oneOf": [
                   {
                       "contains": { "enum": ["date"] },
                       "required": ["resolution"]
                   }
                ]
            },
            "resolution" : {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": ["day", "year", "month", "shift"]
            },
        },
        "required": ["pcsStreamId", "start", "end", "groupBy"]

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve the problem we have to use a boolean logic concept called implication.  To put the requirement in boolean logic terms, we would say "groupBy" contains "date" *implies* that "resolution" is required.  Implication can be expressed as "(not A) or B".  In other words, either "groupBy" does not contain "date", or "resolution" is required.  In this form, it should be more clear how to implement the solution.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "pcsStreamId": { "type": "number" },
    "start": { "type": "integer", "minimum": 0 },
    "end": { "type": "integer", "minimum": 0 },
    "groupBy": {
      "type": "array",
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": { "enum": ["product", "date"] }
    },
    "resolution": { "enum": ["day", "year", "month", "shift"] }
  },
  "required": ["pcsStreamId", "start", "end", "groupBy"],
  "anyOf": [
    { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/contains-date" } },
    { "required": ["resolution"] }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "contains-date": {
      "properties": {
        "groupBy": {
          "contains": { "enum": ["date"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Edit

This answer uses the new draft-06 `contains` keyword.  I used it because the questioner used it, but if you are on draft-04, you can use this definition of "contains-date" instead.  It uses another logic identity (∃x A <=> ¬∀x ¬A) to get the functionality of the `contains` keyword.

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "contains-date": {
      "properties": {
        "groupBy": {
          "not": {
            "items": {
              "not": { "enum": ["date"] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to note that the "contains" keyword works only in json schema draft6 , and currently most of the validators support draft4. Otherwise nice solution :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

Your groupby property seems to be an object. May be its the nested enum property that you are talking about ( since that is an array and contains date and product). However, once you parsed this json to an object you can check something like:

`groupby.items.enums.indexOf('date') === -1`

`array.indexOf(anyItem)` returns the index of the item, if present in the array else it returns -1.

Hope that helps

Comment: Maybe i wrote it not exactly enough. I want to do this in JSON Schema not with application logic. But thx